# Why does Laravel skip my if-statement in Middleware?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have created a Middleware to check if users with google2fa_enabled = 1 have a google2fa_secret and when they don't, they need to create one.

In the Middleware, I have defined the handle function with an if-statement and when true, it redirects the user to /2fa/create. It didn't work, so I made the if-statement like `if(true)`, but the user is not being redirected. When I replace the `return` statement after that with `return redirect('/2fa/create')`, it does redirect, so the middleware is used (also confirmed with the Laravel debugbar)

The Middleware itself:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class checkTwoFactor
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(true){
            redirect('/2fa/create');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And the routes:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('layouts/master');
})->middleware(['auth', 'check2fa']);
```

I expect the user to be redirected to /2fa/create at all times (and later on, if user is logged in, has `google2fa_enabled = 1 & google2fa_secret == ""`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I found the mistake already.

I need a return statement in that if-statement to work, so `redirect()` had to be `return redirect()`